# What is wrong in this string concatenation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new in JavaScript development and I am finding some problem concatenating 2 strings.

So, I done:

```
alert(value);
var pagina = string.concat("edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=", value);
alert(pagina);
```

The **alert(value)** show me the aspected result that is something like: **68661-68662** but the second alert don't show the value of the **pagina** variable so I think that something is going wrong in the concatenation.

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

I need to obtain a string like: **edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=68661-68662**

Tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply doing:

```
var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=" + value;
```

Comment: Overkill is the term that came to my mind after seeing the question. This answer should have been accepted by now:)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var value = "68661-68662";
var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=" + value;
alert(pagina);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up Java with JavaScript.
Contact in javascript is done like this:

```
var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=" + value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "string.concat" is a null pointer, what is "string" in your context? The "string" variable should be the original string.

I guess what you are trying to achieve is:

```
var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=".concat(value);
```

You can also do as Marius suggested:

```
var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.C&ids="+value;
```

Answer (score 1):

To access string methods in JavaScript we use Object oriented design like this: "123".concat("456")

Also note that the class is represented by String, not string.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many acceptable answers here, I want to point out that one  unmentionend method of concatenating strings in JavaScript is using `Array`'s `join()` method:

```
var pagina = ["edi.do?serv=3.C&ids=", value].join();
```